# Spring Boot Integration test doubles by annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am preparing a Spring Boot starter (used for testing) and I want to allow end-user to easily alter production code with some test doubles. These should be modular and independent, i.e:

- in one IT I want to mock Java 8 `Clock @Bean`, which I use for retrieving system time (via `ZonedDateTime.now(clock)`
- in other mock authentication service
- in the 3rd do both

My current solution bases on `AutoConfiguration` classes with `@Profile` and `@Primary @Bean`:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("testClock")
public class FixedClockConfiguration {

    @Value("${neostarter.test.clock:2010-01-10T10:00:00Z}")
    private String fixedClock;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    Clock clock() {
        return Clock.fixed(Instant.parse(fixedClock), TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId());
    }
}
```

Then to use it, I need to set `@ActiveProfiles` in my IT and provide clock value if I don't like the default with `@TestPropertySource`:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
@ActiveProfiles("testClock")
@TestPropertySource(properties = "neostarter.test.clock=2015-05-05T10:00:00Z")
public class IntegrationTest {
```

Same pattern would apply to all test doubles in my IT, hence I would need to add more active profiles (and some test properties possibly):

```
@ActiveProfiles({"testClock", "testAuth"})
```

Is there any way I can translate this to an annotation-based solution? What I would like to achieve is a simple set of annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
@TestClock("2015-05-05T10:00:00Z")
@TestAuth(roles = {"admin", "user"})
public class IntegrationTest {
```

which would do the same thing (or the end result would be the same), where `@TestClock` and `@TestAuth` are fully independent and optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a particularly easy way to do this with Spring Boot 1.3. Probably your best option is to shift the annotations from the test class to the configuration, eg:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration
public class ExampleTests {

    @Autowired
    private Clock clock;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(this.clock);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Import(SampleSimpleApplication.class)
    @TestClock("2015-05-05T10:00:00Z")
    static class Config {
    }

}
```

You can then make `@TestClock` import a registrar:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(TestClockRegistrar.class)
public @interface TestClock {

    String value();

}
```

With the registrar reading the annotation and creating the bean:

```
public class TestClockRegistrar implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {

    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata,
            BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        String pattern = (String) importingClassMetadata
                .getAnnotationAttributes(TestClock.class.getName()).get("value");
        BeanDefinition beanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(Clock.class);
        beanDefinition.setFactoryMethodName("fixed");
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(pattern);
        ZoneId zone = TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId();
        beanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues().addIndexedArgumentValue(0, instant);
        beanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues().addIndexedArgumentValue(1, zone);
        registry.registerBeanDefinition("clock", beanDefinition);
    }

}
```

Of course, I'm not sure this is much better than simply dropping the annotation all together:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration
public class ExampleTests {

    @Autowired
    private Clock clock;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(this.clock);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Import(SampleSimpleApplication.class)
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public Clock clock() {
            Clock.fixed(...)
        }

    }

}
```

We're actively looking at making mock support better for Spring Boot 1.4. You can follow https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5042 for progress.

Comment: Thanks, for the alternative - I really like it. However I have 2 concerns about this solution, where one of them I find blocking: I use @ComponentScan in my application (via @SpringBootApplication), hence second test class still sees and uses the first test static class Config Configuration (and all mocked things associated). The second thing is that In one of my autoconfig classes I set the default TimeZone (in static block) and can't find a way to run this class before the TestClockRegistrar.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have many ideas for how to solve that in 1.3. Hopefully 1.4 will provide more options for you to use. Probably the easiest solution would be to load a different test configuration that doesn't do component scanning. For the static block, you could try Class.forName("") to trigger a load.

Comment: Thank you Phil! I managed to overcome this, but with an ugly solution (keeping test stuff in production code) of having separate meta-annotation for test configurations and exclude it in application `@ComponentScan`. Hence, I sticked with profiles eventually. Can you provide any ETA for better mocking support? Does 1.4.0.M2 still stand for it?

Comment: Yes, It's currently planned for M2.

Comment: It just landed in master, you can try the latest SNAPSHOTs and take a look at the updated docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing

Comment: FYI, I accomplished my mission with Spring Boot 1.4 testing enhancements! Here is a short summary of my journey: http://blog.poznachowski.pl/2016/06/15/mockbean-spring-boot-missing-ingredient/ :)